# Shutdown command fails

Tags: shutdown

Running lxc on my Debian 8 system. Container stopped responding to ssh. lxc-console and lxc-stop were both unresponsive.

```
/etc/init.d/lxc stop
```

was unresponsive. Fine, time to reboot.

`shutdown -r now` has no effect.

Ok...now what? How do I reboot this thing? I have no physical access to the system.

Comment: `sudo shutdown -r now` That is assuming you belong to the group sudoers.

Comment: Like I said, `shutdown -r now` has no effect. All commands run as root of course.

Comment: `sudo shutdown -P -h now` doesn't work either?

Comment: `shutdown -P -h now` does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to reboot such a Linux server *relatively* safely with the specific [Magic SysRq key](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt) sequence: [`REISUB`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses) explained in the Wikipedia article.

For remote servers, if you still have an active remote session with root privilege, you can invoke the same SysRq function by echoing each of the characters above to `/proc/sysrq-trigger`.  But don't issue `R` `E` `I` on remote servers, since `R` is meaningless, `E` and `I` also kill `sshd` you are conntecting to.

```
# echo s >/proc/sysrq-trigger
# echo u >/proc/sysrq-trigger
# echo b >/proc/sysrq-trigger
```